# Docker compose yml inheritance

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

There are two tasks: run app container, run almost the same deploy-app container. The differences for them, for example, that deploy container does not have port sharing.

So, I made configs for this tasks...

`./dockerfiles/base.yml`:

```
app:
    net: docker_internal_net
    environment:
        APPLICATION_SERVER: "docker"
```

`./dockerfiles/base.run.yml`:

```
app:
    container_name: project-app
    # set the build context to the project root
    build: ..
    volumes:
        - /var/log/project/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        - /var/log/project/php-fpm:/var/log/php5-fpm
        - ..:/var/www/project
```

`./dockerfiles/dev/run.yml`:

```
app:
    dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/dev/run-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "22:22"
    environment:
        DEV_SSH_PUBKEY: "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY"
        APPLICATION_PLATFORM: "dev"
```

`./dockerfiles/dev/build.yml`:

```
app:
    container_name: project-app-deploy
    # set the build context to the project root
    build: ../..
    dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/dev/build-app/Dockerfile
    environment:
        APPLICATION_PLATFORM: "dev"
    volumes:
        - ../..:/var/www/project
```

So I can tun the app container like this:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./dockerfiles/base.yml -f ./dockerfiles/base.run.yml -f ./dockerfiles/dev/run.yml up -d app
Creating project-app

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
dae45f3f2c42        dockerfiles_app     "/sbin/my_init"          2 seconds ago       Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:2223->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   project-app
```

Everything okay. But if then I trying to run deploy-app container, I will receive this message:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./dockerfiles/base.yml -f ./dockerfiles/dev/build.yml up -d app
Recreating project-app
WARNING: Service "app" is using volume "/var/www/project" from the previous container. Host mapping ".." has no effect. Remove the existing containers (with `docker-compose rm app`) to use the host volume mapping.

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
53059702c09b        dockerfiles_app     "/sbin/my_init"          6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        22/tcp, 80/tcp      project-app-deploy
```

This is because both of them are shared one local directory? But why I can run deploy-app container manually without `docker-compose`?

```
$ docker run -d --net docker_internal_net -e APPLICATION_SERVER=docker -e APPLICATION_PLATFORM=dev --name project-app-deploy -v ..:/var/www/project mybaseimage
86439874b8df561f529fde0d1e31824d70dc7e2a2377cd529331a2d7fcb00467

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
86439874b8df        mybaseimage         "/sbin/my_init"          4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        22/tcp, 80/tcp                               project-app-deploy
40641f02a09b        dockerfiles_app     "/sbin/my_init"          2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:2223->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   project-app
```

Comment: `Recreating project-app` looks like docker-compose thinks that I manage with the same container, but it is not true, becase the container name are different, they are set into `./dockerfiles/base.run.yml` and `./dockerfiles/dev/build.yml`, which are not includes together.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with the [extend](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) command in that way:

1) making changes into my `./dockerfiles/dev/build.yml` file:

```
deploy-app:
    extends:
        file: ../base.yml
        service: app
    container_name: project-app-deploy
    # set the build context to the project root
    build: ../..
    dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/dev/build-app/Dockerfile
    environment:
        APPLICATION_PLATFORM: "dev"
    volumes:
        - ../..:/var/www/project
```

2) run my deploy app container so:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./dockerfiles/dev/build.yml up -d deploy-app
Building deploy-app
...
Successfully built 74750fe274c6
Creating lovetime-app-deploy

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
9bb2af79ffaa        dev_deploy-app      "/sbin/my_init"          5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        22/tcp, 80/tcp                               project-app-deploy
812b8824f1f0        dockerfiles_app     "/sbin/my_init"          3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:2223->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   project-app

$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' project-app-deploy
[{ ...... /var/www/project  rw true}]
```

**Update**:

According to documentation, this command is not supported in newer compose versions:

> The extends keyword is supported in earlier Compose file formats up to Compose file version 2.1 (see extends in v1 and extends in v2), but is not supported in Compose version 3.x.

Comment: so what's the solution for version 3?